# Data Table Modal details display

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I have taken [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/modal.html) from the internet, but when I try to use it, the modal doesn't pop up. It does however, work in jsfiddle just fine.

I have looked around and found out that the "Collapsed" class is not being applied to the table, which is why it is not working.

Why does it not apply the class to the table?

Comment: http://1stfold.com/taskbox/F.Z/completed/datatable/

Here it is my code. That is not working.

Comment: Please show the relevant the code.

Comment: Everything is working as it should, if you resize your window, to a smaller size, it'll display the details button, just make your table width smaller.

Comment: Thanks William-H-M. But why it don't work greater then 1100 width? Please can you tell me?

Comment: It's because has enough space to be displayed, that's how responsive works, if it sees there's enough width on the screen it'll throw everything, anyway I suggest you to set the table width smaller or surround with a div.

Comment: William-H-M I have add width. But it does not work width more then 300. And 300 is very small is it possible to work it on about 980px?

Answer (score 1):

As @[William-H-M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8538799/william-h-m) already said in the comments, it is working fine and has to do with the width of the screen. You just need to control your screen width to make it work. Place the table in a div and set the max width to 1000px.

```
<div style="max-width: 1000px;">
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;">
    <!-- table content -->
  </table>
<div>
```